# undefined is not a function in DrawerView

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I upgraded React Native from version 0.64.0 to 0.71.2. my react navigation is on version 5.
As soon as my DrawerNavigator gets unmounted i get this warning as when we flush all the screens from stack and go back to LoginScreen.

`Warning: Internal React error: Attempted to capture a commit phase error inside a detached tree. This indicates a bug in React. Likely causes include deleting the same fiber more than once, committing an already-finished tree, or an inconsistent return pointer.

Error message:

TypeError: undefined is not a function
in DrawerView (created by DrawerNavigator)
in DrawerNavigator (created by DrawerNavigator)
in DrawerNavigator (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View
in CardSheet (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Card)
in Card (created by CardContainer)
in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)`

my react navigation packages are of version

`"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10", "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.15", "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5", "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.15", "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4", "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",`

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error that you posted and it took me a while to fix it.

I build my project using expo and I was using react-navigation together with react-native-paper. After upgrading my project so that I could keep using the expo app for testing I started getting this error.

I noticed that even after running npm install (or npx expo install ) some of the libraries would stay on the same version in my package.json even though newer version were available.

I had to first uninstall those libraries using npm uninstall  and then reinstall them to get the latest version. This fixed the error for me, it did cause other problems because of some breaking changes in the newer version, but those were easier to fix.

I hope this helps.